# For the Google assistant API running on Pi4B, using Python 3, how do I enable the connection to a Bluetooth device?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, pi

Essentially as the title says, I'm trying to connect my Google Assistant API to a Bluetooth speaker, but it prioritises the the speaker that's connected to my Blue Yeti microphone. If I disconnect the speaker, it will still register the Yeti as a speaker, even after a reboot. I'm honestly unsure of how to integrate this, and all online tutorials I've found thus far have failed. The Bluetooth speaker does show up with it's MAC address. I am still a beginner at Python/Linux, but all help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/audio ? Some more details of what you have tried and what is failing would be helpful.

Comment: The problem I've realised is that when I go to do aplay -l, it brings up my blue yeti as the output, but the UE boom doesn't register.